# How to view and save the WordCloud generated in Python

Tags: python, word-cloud

I am trying to generate a **WordCloud** in Python from a `.csv` file.

This is how my `.csv` file looks like:

```
title,views
universe,45678
earth,34366
smtp,4567987
```

This is what I did to create the **WordCloud**:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as pPlot
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

reader = csv.reader(open('C:/Users/Sushma/Downloads/wordcloud.csv', 'r', newline = '\n', encoding = 'utf-8'))

for k, v in reader:
    d[k] = float(v)

wordcloud = WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(d)
```

If I print **WordCloud**, I get an object **id**.

Can anybody please suggest how to save this as an image and how to view it on Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there are some errors in your code:

**1.** The `.csv` file must be placed in a `list` for reading:

```
with open('C:/Users/Sushma/Downloads/wordcloud.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf8', newline = '\r\n') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace = False, delimiter = ',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    data = list(reader)
```

**2.** After this, a `dictionary` must be created that contains the key and the value in `int` format so that later, we can create the **WordCloud**:

```
word_freq = {}
for k, v in data[1:]:
   word_freq[k] = int(v)
```

Now, you need to create a `variable` that will receive the multiplication between the **text** and its **frequency**:

```
text = ' '.join([(k + ' ') * v for k, v in word_freq.items()])
```

Then, you will create the **WordCloud** that will receive this variable `text`:

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 1600,
                      height = 800,
                      background_color = 'white',
                      collocations = False,
                      repeat = True).generate_from_text(text)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation = "bilinear")
plt.axis('off')
```

And now you can simply save the generated **WordCloud**:

```
plt.savefig(f'wordcloud.png',
            dpi = 300)
```

To plot (visualize) just use:

```
plt.show()
```

**Final result:**

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeS7E.png)

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please, up-vote and mark this answer as accepted! Thanks!